# Disable Doom Emacs auto pairs

Tags: doom

I'm new to Doom Emacs and Emacs in general and the problem I have with it is that it pairs characters automatically, for example when I want to insert single double quote sign like this `"` it inserts two double quote signs like this: `""`. I know that this feature is probably very useful for many people but I'd like to make it insert single quote instead of pair. If you know how to solve my problem please make your answer as easy to understand as possible. Also please forgive me any mistakes in my writing as I'm not a native speaker nor do I know english very well.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the doom emacs [FAQ](https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/blob/3b789752a30419535b328c605957b6b43a9d47fa/docs/faq.org#how-to-disable-smartparensautomatic-parentheses-completion)

```lisp
(remove-hook 'doom-first-buffer-hook #'smartparens-global-mode)
```

Would need to be added to `~/.doom.d/config.el`